# APEX test user creation

Tags: unit-test, user

This is probably a very silly question but I recall on some forums a conversation in regards to this subject. I'm working on my code coverage for an apex class. For that test I need to use the user object to obtain certain information from a number of users. I need to get access to Country, Title, and some other information, can be from any user.

This is not big deal.
The question is,

**if need I users for my test, should I use real user ids?**

or

**Can I create users inside the test class?**

Why I asking this... I believe, like a mentioned on the first lines of this post, that I need to have free licences in order for me to create those users on the test class. I think that a conversation on this subject took place with Jeff Douglas in a forum, but can't remember the outcome of it. 
Anyone can explain what is the actual situation on this matter?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Taken from the [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_testing_tools_runas.htm):

> Generally, all Apex code runs in system mode, where the permissions and record sharing of the current user are not taken into account. The system method `runAs` enables you to write test methods that change the user context to an existing user or a new user so that the user’s record sharing is enforced. The `runAs` method doesn’t enforce user permissions or field-level permissions, only record sharing.
>
> You can use `runAs` only in test methods. The original system context is started again after all `runAs` test methods complete.
>
> **The `runAs` method ignores user license limits. You can create new users with `runAs` even if your organization has no additional user licenses.**
>
> ```
> @isTest
> private class TestRunAs {
>     public static testMethod void testRunAs() {
>         // Setup test data
>         // This code runs as the system user
>         Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Standard User']; 
>         User u = new User(Alias = 'standt', Email='standarduser@testorg.com', 
>             EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', 
>             LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id, 
>             TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='standarduser@testorg.com');
>
>         System.runAs(u) {
>             // The following code runs as user 'u' 
>             System.debug('Current User: ' + UserInfo.getUserName());
>             System.debug('Current Profile: ' + UserInfo.getProfileId()); 
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: The documentation has been updated, and the way I read it, the runAs method now DOES enforce user permissions:

The runAs method enforces record sharing. User permissions and field-level permissions are applied for the new context user as described in Enforcing Object and Field Permissions. (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_tools_runas.htm?q=runas)

Answer (score 8):

Building on this answer, I construct my test classes `@TestSetup` methods such that I can create an arbitrary number of unique users using a shortened 8-char GUID to init the names and emails, like so:

```
@IsTest  
public with sharing class NotificationTests {
  @TestSetup  
  private static void setup() {    
    // Setup 4 Test Users
    Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Standard User']; 
    List<User> uu = new List<User>();

    while (uu.size() < 5) {
      Blob b = Crypto.GenerateAESKey(128);
      String h = EncodingUtil.ConvertTohex(b);
      String uid = h.SubString(0,8);
      User u = new User(Alias = uid, Email= uid + '@myorg.com', 
          EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', 
          LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id, 
          TimeZoneSidKey='America/New_York', UserName= uid + '@myorg.com');      
      uu.add(u);
    }
    insert(uu);
  }

  @IsTest
  public static void myTest() {
    /* ... */
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Shane. Now I don't insert the users anymore on the test classes, it is bad practice..... that's if you believe on anything that Dan Appleman has to say about Apex :) ...

Comment: Hmmm.  But what is the alternative if you need a user in your test?  Note I think this only makes sense with `SeeAllData=false`; also I typically develop using DX scratch orgs that have no data at all :).

Comment: I never use **SeeAllData=true** ... the approach I use is to add , not to insert, a user in your test class. Salesforce creates this temporary space for that User and you can pass his Id or any other field to your test class without doing any DML operation.

Comment: That is nice unless you have more than one test method in your class which needs to use the same dataset.  Maybe Dan Appleman is too much of a purist ;)

Comment: @CarlosNaranjo What exactly constitutes inserting a user in a test class as a bad practice?

Comment: @CarlosNaranjo Can you elaborate on what Dan Appleman has to say about inserting users in Apex test classes?  A link would be great!